# Should library be updated, when .h file is updated?

Tags: c++, header-files

I have already sent our customer our library(`.a`, `.so`) along with `.h` files.

Now i have few changes in `.h` file. So my question is, do I need to send the updated `.a` , `.so` or sending `.h` would work.

Customer would replace `.h` files with old `.h`.

Will this work?

Comment: Depends on the changes. What kind of things have you done? You could *test* this in your environment.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and assume the customer is *programming* with your library, because if not it seems somewhat pointless to send them a header at all.

Comment: moved definiton of member function of class .. which was there outside class. moved it inside class , to make it inline..

Comment: dude, you need to send a new library if you changed it! :-) More seriously: The class layout seems to have changed, so even if you didn't change your cpp files the resulting object code will look differently after a recompile (e.g. compare the symbols being exported by the two versions of your lib!).

Comment: Re-reading your post I'm now less sure because I think you didn't change the interface (API) but just moved an implementation inside the class declaration. Hm. I'm not sure the vtable (if any) would change in that case (provided the order of members didn't change). The class layout certainly wouldn't. Client code may change though, obviously (that's the whole point!). Test extensively ...

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you updated in the .h file.

If you updated something that doesn't require a recompilation (e.g. some comments?), then you could just give the updated .h file.

But, *in general*, I think that to be safe, if you change the header, it's a good practice to **recompile** the whole module (so, you may want to resend to your clients the object and library binary files).

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely must redistribute if you've moved a member function declaration.

This is because any v-table will be invalidated.

Inlining will also change the linking behaviour: the old library will export a decorated non-inline function which is inconsistent with the behaviour specified by the new version of you header.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should upgrade .h with .a/.so. E.g. you have change some data structure that it's now bigger/smaller. You can get heap corrupter error with simply updating header.

Answer (score 0):

One question to ask yourself is: What would 'scons' do?

I have some projects which use [scons](http://www.scons.org/) as the build tool. I have noticed when I change a header file that scons always compiles the affected modules, but sometimes doesn't feel the need to rebuild the libraries or executables of which they are components.

In general is it good practise to recompile everything before releasing to the customer, but if scons finds that it doesn't need to rebuild, then in fact you should release nothing.